# How to control the handset using AT commands in java

Tags: java, at-command

I know that by using AT commands we can control the handset.As example unlocking screen we can give a specific AT command or moving right to the menu or left or bottom or up we can give specific AT commands. What all are the AT commands for doing this kind of control.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List of AT commands](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/AT_Commands)

sample java code to use AT command

```
 public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord serviceRecord[])
    {
        String url = serviceRecord[0].getConnectionURL(1, false);
try
        {
            //ClientSession conn= (ClientSession)Connector.open(url);
            StreamConnection meineVerbindung = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url);

            if(conn== null)
                System.out.println("Kann Service URL nicht oeffnen\n");
            else
            {

                OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
                InputStream in = conn.openInputStream();

                String message = "AT+CGMI\r\n";

                // send AT-command
                System.out.println("send AT Comand request: "+message);
                out.write(message.getBytes());

                out.flush();
                out.close();

                byte buffer[] = new byte[10000];
                // read the response from mobile phone
                in.read(buffer);
                System.out.println("AT Comand response: "+buffer.toString());}            

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Service Error(3): "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nice, please change `conn.openOutputStream();` to `meineVerbindung.openOutputStream()`

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, the AT commands are more used for phone-type functions (making calls, or sending SMS, etc), rather than menu navigation, etc.

I'm not entirely sure if that was your end-goal after menu navigation, but you can find more details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set (the original +AT command set)

If you wanted to send SMS from a handset connected to your computer you might want to take a peek at this page: http://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp
If you wanted more control when performing functions, like sending SMS, etc, you might want to investigate "PDU Mode."

It is entirely possible that some handset manufacturers may have implemented additional +AT commands to allow other functions to be performed, so you might do better by specifically searching for the commands related to the handset you are using.

(Of course, if you're having issues connecting to the handset hardware itself, you need to ensure you have either the javax.comm extension or some favoured Java USB API installed)

If post doesn't help, perhaps you could provide more details in your question? (eg. what you are ultimately trying to do, if you think it would help)